# Area-51 Different count of badges been shown at proposal and user pages

Tags: support, area-51, badges

I've earned 6 bronze badges in Area-51, but it shows 3 everytime, except when I go to a proposal page or discussion zone. May I know the reason behind that? Is it a bug?

[image: 3 Badge Image][image: 6 badge Image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the same as on 2.0 meta sites and has the same meta badge set.  Just as on site metas the badges (with the exception of convention and quorum) are earned separately.

Your three [badges on Area 51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/52637/creator) (Pioneer, advocate and autobiographer) are both **different** and **separate** from the [seven badges you have earned](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/52637/creator?tab=badges) on the discussion zone, just as they would be on any other meta site.  Pioneer and advocate are not available on discussion.

I'd be very surprised if this wasn't by-design =)

Comment: *Phew* and I thought it was a bug, and it's just me. Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

First one is your **main area51 user** profile that refer to commitment proposal, example questions etc...

And the second one is the **discussion user** profile that refer to global Q&A you made.