# Badges not being displayed on AREA51 account

Tags: bug, badges

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Area-51 Different count of badges been shown at proposal and user pages](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/122831/area-51-different-count-of-badges-been-shown-at-proposal-and-user-pages)

I have two tabs open in same browser as

[discuss.area51](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/) and
[area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/)

on the page of discuss.area51 it is showing badges count as 3
and on the area51 badges it is as 1 but with same reputation.

I want to know whether both accounts are different or it is a bug.

Comment: @Rory thanks.I should have done more research earlier.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both accounts are different.

All meta sites(except MSO) have the same rep system as their parent site. Upvotes/downvotes/blah on these sites do not affect any rep.

On the other hand, metas have a completely different, meta-specific badge system.

- http://area51.stackexchange.com/badges
- https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/badges (Note the lack of an "activist" badge)

On a normal SE 2.0 site:

- https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/badges
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/badges

As well as me having completely different badge counts there:

- https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/users/7433/manishearth
- https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/7433/manishearth

Answer (score 2):

The [Area51 Discussion Zone](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/) ("discuss") is the Meta site for [Area51](http://area51.stackexchange.com/) ("main site"), they are different sites, similarly to how Stack Overflow is a different site from Meta Stack Overflow.

So, in your [main Area51 user profile](http://area51.stackexchange.com/users/55123/) shows only the badges earned on the main site and your [discussion user profile](https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/users/55123/heyanshukla) shows only the badges earned on the discussion site.